# What namespace is required for DataClassesDataContext?

Tags: c#, linq

What namespace should I use to get access to `DataClassesDataContext`? I have tried the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Excel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: I think you are looking for DataContext from the System.Data.Linq.dll, right ?

Comment: google -> DataClassesDataContext -> lucky shot ...

Comment: I don't think there is any such class. Where did you find this? There is a class DataContext for performing database related operations.

Comment: i want  to import excel file sql server that i writing a program ,i need the DataClassesDataContext overthere.

Comment: @VanajaDasi can you paste an error also?

Comment: It's in whatever namespace your teacher put it in.